# How to detect null values in shell?

Tags: shell, unix

HI all,

I wrote this code but it doesn't catch any of the two variables being null, why?

```
echo "$var1 - $var2"

if [ "$var1" == ""] || [ "$var2" == ""]
then
    echo "Incomplete data"
    exit 1
fi
```

The initial echo prints nothing for the variables when I run my script so the if statement should work right? But it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Actually the issue was that there's no space between "" and closing ]. WOW!

Comment: Which shell are you writing for? Bourne shell for portability or Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` has a different meaning in the shell. Also `==` is not used for comparison; `=` is. Maybe you meant:

```
 if [ -z "$var1" -o -z "$var2" ]
```

Quoting from the manpage:

```
EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
              either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true

-z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're writing a Bash script since you're using `==` and Bourne doesn't have that if I recall correctly.

I understand that your problem was due to lack of spaces before the brackets, but you should make your `if` look like this:

```
if [[ "$var1" == "" || "$var2" == "" ]]
```

if for no other reason than it executes faster. However, the double square bracket also buys you [additional capabilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Answer (score 0):

you can use case/esac

```
case "$var1$var2" in "" ) echo "null";; esac
```